# Nextjs13 - Scrolling is not functional between the layout and the main page

Tags: css, next.js, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

First, sorry for any grammer issues, english is not my native language.

I have a navbar that's defined in my layout component in Nextjs 13. My problem is that I can't find a way to make it scroll down with my main page that contains 13 slides (every slide is 100vh except the first one that is 90vh).

I want the layout component to stay SSR and only my SlideShow component that I've imported in the main page.tsx to be CSR.

How can I do it purely with CSS?

The Layout component:

```
import Link from "next/link"
import '@/app/globals.css'

const MENU_ITEMS = [
    { title: 'Lollipop', path: '/' },
    { title: 'About', path: '/about' }
]

export default function AppHeader() {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="appHeader">
                <div className="flex mx-auto max-w-5xl">
                    <ul className="flex gap-4">
                        {MENU_ITEMS.map((item)=> (
                        <li key={item.path} className="text-black-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium">
                            <Link href={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
                        </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </div>   
            </nav>
            </div>
    )
}
```

The SlideShow component that is the main page of my project:

```
'use client'

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./SlideShow.module.css";

const SlideShow: React.FC = () => {
  const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      setCurrentSlide((prevSlide) => prevSlide + 1);
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const slideContainer = document.getElementById("slideContainer");
    if (slideContainer) {
      slideContainer.style.height = `${(currentSlide + 1) * 100}vh`;
    }
  }, [currentSlide]);

  return (
    <div id="slideContainer" className={styles.slideContainer} style={{marginTop:'10vh'}}>
        <div className={styles.slide} style={{ height: currentSlide === 0 ? "90vh" : "100vh" }}>
          <div className={styles.slide} style={{ top: `${currentSlide * 100}vh` }}>
            Slide 1
          </div>
          {/*The rest of the slides*/}
};

export default SlideShow;
```

I tried to use CSS but the page won't recognize that the two conmponents is connected.
The website makes the navbar 'sticky' and only the main page scrolls down.

Thanks for everybody who helps!